# Tiles 2 Access Variable in Template

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, tiles2, apache-tiles

I am using the Spring MVC framework with Apache Tiles 2. I want to be able to have multiple controllers all use the same view (different logic, some basic presentation). I can do that easily. What I want now is to have different Tiles definitions for each controller, all using the same JSP file, but each passing different template variables (page header, short description, etc). This is my Tiles template definition file:

```
<tiles-definitions>

    <!-- Default Main Template -->
    <definition name=".mainTemplate" template="/WEB-INF/templates/main.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="shortTitle" value="Company ABC" type="string" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/templates/blank.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <!-- Overriding Templates -->
    <definition name="index" extends=".mainTemplate">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Company Alpha Bravo Charlie" type="string" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="index2" extends=".mainTemplate">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Company Other Page" type="string" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp" />
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

I then try to have this `/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp`:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>

<h1>
    Hello world, it's <tiles:getAsString name="title" />!  
</h1>
```

When I load this into Tomcat and bring up the page, I get a long stack trace of exceptions. The top of the pile says `org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/templates/main.jsp'.} with root cause org.apache.tiles.template.NoSuchAttributeException: Attribute 'title' not found`. Anybody know what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I then try to have this /WEB-INF/views/index.jsp:

How do you try this? In your controller you would specify the name of the Tiles view, not one of the multiple JSP Tiles will use in order to render the page:

```
@RequestMapping("index2")
public String index2() {
    // ...
    return "index2";
}
```

Comment: At this point in my development, there is no controller, I have a `<mvc:view-controller path="/index.html" />`. This seems to be getting me to the template I want, but I certainly have no idea how.

Comment: Please, try it with a Controller, because I have some ver similar examples and it works with no problem.

Comment: I am struggling to do that, so any advice you can give me would be much appreciated.